# remove checkbox and text value when combobox change

Tags: javascript, text, checkbox, combobox

I have an issue with my code. I hope anybody here can help me to fix it. I have problem in remove value from text on change event of `select` input .

Here is my js code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select').change(function() {
    var check = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('id');
    $('#' + check + '').prop("checked", false);
    var txt = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type='text']").attr('id');
    $('#' + txt + '').val("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>SELECT TYPE</th>
    <th>TAKE IT</th>
    <th>YOUR CHOOSEN</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="select" name="select1">
        <option>--CHOOSE--</option>
        <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
        <option value="Bike">Bike</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="input1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="select" name="select2">
        <option>--CHOOSE--</option>
        <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
        <option value="Bike">Bike</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="input2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="select" name="select3">
        <option>--CHOOSE--</option>
        <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
        <option value="Bike">Bike</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check3" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="input3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: I am loading data from database and showing the result into text and check-box automatically checked according to customer choice. When the customer want to edit data so, they will change the select input and the text and check-box should be clear. I only can remove the checked check-box but can't clear the text. Anybody please help. I really appreciate for any help.

Comment: Hi Clara T , what do you want , I have tried you code in fact this cannot use , so that please give us specific your question or you want .

Comment: _What is not working ?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having a problem to get how the script is working.

```
 var check = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('id');

 var txt = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type='text']").attr('id');
```

this two code look for the `id` of `input checkbox` and the `input text`.

As I see there is no `id` defined for these two element. So those variable will have nothing in them (`undefined`) hence the code will not work.

**One solve is:**

You can add id to those field. Like

```
<tr>
  <td><select class="select" name="select1">
  <option>--CHOOSE--</option><option value="Cars">Cars</option><option value="Bike">Bike</option>
  </select> </td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" /></td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  <select class="select" name="select2"><option>--CHOOSE--</option><option value="Cars">Cars</option><option value="Bike">Bike</option>
  </select></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" /></td>
```

**Another Solve:**

You can modify you script like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.select').change(function(){

        var check =         $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type='checkbox']");
    
        $(check).prop("checked",false);
        var txt = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type='text']");
     
        $(txt).val("");
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry I just forget to add id in my question but actually, in my original form i have an id. I've already try it and it works. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.select').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='text']").val("");        $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",false);
});});
```

Please try this friend i will work fine